# Changing language in LaTeX poster template

Tags: fonts, fontspec, languages

I downloaded a template for conference posters from link below:
[template](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/conference-posters). But when I change the language to 'Persian', it doesn't work. For example I write "علی عباسی"
instead of 'John Smith' but after running the code, it doesn't show
"علی عباسی".
Could anyone help?

Comment: my guess is, you need to add `\usepackage[persian]{babel}` to the code. but since you haven't provided a MWE, it's just that: an estimated guess.

Comment: There are six templates on that website, could you specify which one you downloaded?